# Merge Python Pandas Index only or combine multiIndex Cartesian with multiIndex aggregates to show in-use vs not in use

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Summary of issue:  I am attempting to merge an index into another index on some multiindex dataframes so I can see what is in use vs what is not in use.  One dataframe is a list of departments with a Cartesian of date ranges of interest, the other is aggregated data grouped by the department ids and some basic dates.

Details:  I have two dataframes.  One has departmental data grouped by a date range.  The other is a full list of departments with a cartesian of all the date ranges it is possible to report on.

Since the departmental data may be omitting some date ranges, I need to see there was no output for that range, which is why I am using the cartesian in the other view.  The date ranges will not always be the same and will not always be exact years.

For example:

```
df1:
                scheduled, completed, other
timeframe, dept
2017-01-01 1,   35,        34,        5
2017-01-01 3,   67,        84,        4   
2018-01-01 4,   74,        43,        99

df2:
                        range
id, name,   interval
1,  dept a, 2017-01-01  [2017-01-01, 2017-06-30 23:59:59]
            2018-01-01  [2018-01-01, 2018-06-30 23:59:59]
2,  dept b, 2017-01-01  [2017-01-01, 2017-06-30 23:59:59]
            2018-01-01  [2018-01-01, 2018-06-30 23:59:59]
3,  dept c, 2017-01-01  [2017-01-01, 2017-06-30 23:59:59]
            2018-01-01  [2018-01-01, 2018-06-30 23:59:59]
4,  dept d, 2017-01-01  [2017-01-01, 2017-06-30 23:59:59]
            2018-01-01  [2018-01-01, 2018-06-30 23:59:59]
5,  dept e, 2017-01-01  [2017-01-01, 2017-06-30 23:59:59]
            2018-01-01  [2018-01-01, 2018-06-30 23:59:59]
```

My desired result is:

```
                       scheduled, completed, other
id, name,  interval
1, dept a, 2017-01-01  35,        34,        5
           2018-01-01  
2, dept b, 2017-01-01  
           2018-01-01  
3, dept c, 2017-01-01   67,       84,        4  
           2018-01-01  
4, dept d, 2017-01-01  
           2018-01-01   74,       43,        99
5, dept e, 2017-01-01  
           2018-01-01
```

I have tried the following:

- Union the Index - errored because it does not work with dataframe
- Merge the Frames - Errored because I wanted to merge Index Only from 
  df2 and not columns
- Join the Frames - Errored and/or undid my aggregations and groupbys
  feeding df1
- PD Cut - Had many issues getting this to work across the two frames

I have thought about doing an outer apply (then filtering) of everything or using iterrows, however, I do not believe this would be performant or efficient as some frames in use will potentially have hundreds of thousands of rows (or millions).  Once this is merged, the data is actually to be pivoted, so I would prefer to keep my index, stacking, and aggregations intact if possible so it doesn't break some of the other functions in the script.

The problem I seem to be having:
Because I want to introduce the Cartesian of dates and departments to show which have output vs which ones do not, I really only want to perform a "Union" like merge on the Index to fill in the dates and departments which are missing from the dataframe as well as include/display the department names.  I believe my process may be flawed and I am not going about this properly.